# In Kohana/PHP, how can send execution to a new controller/action?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

In PHP/Kohana, I have controller action method which does some processing. When it is finished, I want to send it to another controller, e.g.:

```
public function action_import_csv()
{
    Kohana_Import_Driver_Csv::process_files_from_csv_to_mysql($this->import_directory);
    //url::redirect(Route::get('backend_application')->uri()); //undefined method URL::redirect()
    //redirect(Route::get('backend_application')->uri(), null); //undefined function
}
```

According to [this documentation](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/helpers/url) at least the first redirect should work. I'm using **Kohana 3**.

**How can I send execution from this controller action method to a new controller/action?**

## Addendum

For some reason, url::redirect is not available, here is the code completion I get for `url::`:

[image]

@bharath, I tried `url::current()` and got this error:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are looking at the Kohana 2 docs. Go to the kohana homepage and find the correct docs. Also, for some reason, everyone is giving you Kohana 2 answers even though you stated you're working with 3.

To redirect, do this from the context of a controller:
`$this->request->redirect($something);`

`$something` could be:

```
controller
controller/action
http://url.com
```

[Here](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/Request#redirect) are the api docs for the `redirect` method (note that this uses `url::site` to parse the url; you may want to look at the source of that method too.

Comment: that makes sense, this has happened before, so the kohana 3 docs are here http://kohanaframework.org/guide, what is the best way to search for "url::" or "redirect" within the kohana 3 docs, as this page doesn't have a search box

Comment: @Edward: That's the guide, here are the [api docs](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api), which are searchable. The guide is more of a tutorial, the api docs are more of a reference.

Comment: But url is a static class, and as it exists it should have the redirect method, as stated in the documentation.

Comment: ok, in the future I'm going to search for information on kohana3 like this: `site:http://kohanaframework.org/guide url redirect`

Comment: @RobertPitt: You're looking at the wrong docs. In kohana 3, [there is no redirect method on the url class](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/URL).

Answer (score 0):

i am not very sure but i think you can simple use the `redirect()` function passing in the other controller you want to send to with any parameters

example

```
redirect(controllername/method)
```

Comment: when I try that as posted above I get `Call to undefined function redirect()`, but even the url::redirect() version doesn't work, it's not getting an erorr, but it doesn't redirect to the new controller, I'm trying to find out what exactly it is doing if anything

Comment: well redirect() will be a part of the url class therefore you need to do do something like this url::redirect(controllername/method);. this is assuming that the url class is loaded. if not load the url class and try this. hope this helps.

Comment: are you trying to redirect to a different controller or a method within the same controller?....i use codeigniter and this is how its done there and bcoz kohana is built upon it i'd assume it to be the same...

Comment: I have errors on, for some reason it doesn't even recognize `url::redirect` as stated it should in the documentation, I get the error `ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method URL::redirect()`, I don't even get "redirect" in the code completion, see above

Comment: I tried url::current() and got the above error, see screenshot

Comment: @bharath: This entire answer is wrong because you're giving him a Kohana 2 solution to a Kohana 3 problem.

Comment: @ryeguy, i was just trying to help in some way possible, i don't use kohana so i wouldn't know all the versions, however its very similar to codeigniter so thought i'd be of some help....sorry for misguiding Edward Tanguay

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be :

```
url::redirect('controller/method');
```

And if it doesn't work, you probably had some output before calling the redirect (you'll probably get the "Headers already sent" error when that is the case).

Comment: technically that should work but I don't even get "redirect" in my code completion for `url::`, see above screenshot, what could be causing this?